# Name of a game / activity where one communicates with gestures

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

In the [3rd round](https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/celebrities-party-game-rules-412175) of the game Celebrities, one has to communicate a celebrity to his partner by acting/gesturing without words. Is there a name of that activity?

Is it maybe possible to use [play mime](https://www.familyeducation.com/fun/play-acting/play-mime) as a phrase outside the context of theatre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This game is known as [Charades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charades). People can "play Charades" or "play a round of Charades."

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to use it outside of context of games? Like when I'd like to describe someone using body language: "As he couldn't speak any Vietnamese, he played mime/charades/mimed for the locals." ?

Comment: @Probably Yes, either "he played charades" or "he mimed" would work in that sentence. I've never heard "played mime."

Answer (score 2):

If you're not actually playing a game and you're just trying to use gestures to communicate because of a language barrier, you could say something like

> He [mimed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mime) driving a car hoping that the locals would understand he was looking for a taxi.

or

> Conversations were mostly in mime, because he didn't know much Vietnamese.

Here is a "real life" example:

> He let us know (**mostly in mime** since we don’t know French and he didn’t know English) that if we needed anything this was where he lived and he would be happy to help. ([Source](https://sv-bellavita.blogspot.com/2013/06/))

If you say "play mime", as in the title of the article you linked in the question, you're saying something similar to "play at being a mime" or "pretend like you are a mime". We could also say something like "Hey kids, lets play *take a nap*!"